# I want to download input file submit by user

Tags: php, laravel

I want to download a file from the website. But I am getting error while doing that. So lets say user fill in the form and upload cv, it will store in database and I have the file inside my public/uploads/image in laravel. However I want it to be download inside the admin server-side. when admin see the user's list, and click "download" button. It will be able to download the cv. Any help is much appreciate because I just learn about laravel this week. should I create new controller just to download it? can I just use the same controller when user upload their cv? My error message is *Missing required parameters for [Route: download] [URI: download/{file}].*

**ListController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'fullname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'contact' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'attachment' => 'required|mimes:pdf,docx,doc|max:2048',
        
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();

    if ($request->has('attachment')) {
      
        $file = $request->file('attachment');
        $text = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $name = $input['fullname'];
        $folder = '/uploads/images/';
        $filePath = $folder . $name. '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $this->uploadOne($file, $folder, 'public', $name);

    }

    Form::create($request->all());
    return view('form.index');

    public function download($file)
   {

    $file_path = public_path('uploads/images/'.$file);
    return response()->download( $file_path);
   }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/download/{file}','CandidateController@download')->name('download');
```

**form.blade.php** *this is the button for the download*

```
<h2 class="font-medium text-base mr-auto">Download CV</h2> <button class="button border items- center text-gray-700 dark:border-dark-5 dark:text-gray-300 hidden sm:flex"> <i data-feather="file"  href="{{ route('download',$candidate->file) }}" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2"></i> Download Docs </button>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how this looks inside the browser itself please? `href="{{ route('download',$candidate->file) }}"`

Comment: I update my question. apparently when user click download button the pop up window will appear like the above and when user click download docs, the resume should be downloaded

Comment: Hello, missing parameter clearly shows that your `$candidate->file` returns `null` so try to print or `dd($candidate->file)` to see if you are actually passing this

Comment: @MuaRachmann i tried and I have my file

Comment: Like @thursday_dan said can we see the outcome of `{ { route('download',$candidate->file) }}`

Comment: Is $candidate->file the file name or a file object?

Answer (score 0):

When it says `the missing required parameter`, It mostly means the file is not sent.

Try this one:

`href="{{ route('download', ['file' => $candidate->file]) }}"`,

In your controller:

`public function download(Request $request) { public_path('uploads/images/'. $request->get('file')) }`

Comment: it still showing the same error like before *Missing required parameters for [Route: download] [URI: download/{file}]* the error is in my blade

Comment: We debugged this, did not you find a solution?

Comment: I need more details, maybe I could help
if you have whatsapp or something to chat,
You can be in access more and we can find a solution to it easier